# Equivalent of tf.SparseFeature in tf.data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

The neural network I am currently working on is accepting a sparse tensor as input. I am reading my data from a TFRecord as follows:

```
_, examples = tf.TFRecordReader(options=options).read_up_to(
    filename_queue, num_records=batch_size)

features = tf.parse_example(examples, features={
          'input_feat': tf.SparseFeature(index_key='input_feat_idx',
                                         value_key='input_feat_values',
                                         dtype=tf.int64,
                                         size=SIZE_FEATURE)})
```

It works like a charm but I was looking at the `tf.data` API which looks more convenient for a lot of tasks and I am not sure how to read `tf.SparseTensor` objects like I do with the `tf.RecordReader` and `tf.parse_example()`. Any idea?

Answer (score 4):

TensorFlow 1.5 will add native support for `tf.SparseTensor` in the core transformations. (This is currently available if you `pip install tf-nightly`, or build from source on the master branch of TensorFlow.) This means that you can write your pipeline as the following:

```
# Create a dataset of string records from the input files.
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordReader(filenames)

# Convert each string record into a `tf.SparseTensor` representing a single example.
dataset = dataset.map(lambda record: tf.parse_single_example(
    record, features={'input_feat': tf.SparseFeature(index_key='input_feat_idx',
                                                     value_key='input_feat_values',
                                                     dtype=tf.int64,
                                                     size=SIZE_FEATURE)})

# Stack together up to `batch_size` consecutive elements into a `tf.SparseTensor`
# representing a batch of examples.
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)

# Create an iterator to access the elements of `dataset` sequentially.
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()

# `next_element` is a `tf.SparseTensor`.
next_element = iterator.get_next()
```